# Trying to run service that access to X server under systemd

Tags: linux, go, daemon, systemd, archlinux

I'm using manjaro linux (arch based) with systemd. I want to make a daemon service that runs in the background and takes screenshots of my screen at random intervals, up to 10 minutes apart.

I'm using Go, and I have a program that works just fine if I build it and run it from the command line (see below). I've made a .service file (see below) for the service and I've started it with `systemctl start screenshot` and confirmed it's running with `systemctl is-active screenshot`. However, it doesn't work. No screenshots are being saved like if I run it from the command line.

Out of interest I tried running it with `nohup ./screenshot &` and it suffers from the same problem as my daemon attempt.

Is there some sort of problem with using the date package in the background? Or could it perhaps be the screenshot library?

`screenshot.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/png"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/coreos/go-systemd/daemon"
    "github.com/vova616/screenshot"
)

func main() {
    daemon.SdNotify(false, "READY=1")
    i := 0
    for {
        r := rand.Intn(10)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Minute)
        t := time.Now()
        year, month, day := t.Date()
        date := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%s-%d", year, month.String(), day)
        img, err := screenshot.CaptureScreen()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        hour, min, sec := t.Clock()
        stamp := fmt.Sprintf("%d:%d:%d", hour, min, sec)
        fmt.Printf("Taking screenshot %s\n", stamp)
        f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("/home/dave/screenshot/%s/%s.png", date, stamp))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        err = png.Encode(f, img)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        err = f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        i++
        daemon.SdNotify(false, "WATCHDOG=1")
    }
}
```

and here is the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Random Screenshot Service

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/home/dave/screenshot/screenshot
WatchdogSec=30s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the journal?

Comment: If you need a service to have access to your X server, you can't run it in systemd, you need to run it from within X. The best way to do this probably depends on which DE/window manager you're using. But this is probably best asked on Super User, as it's really about how to start a service in X, rather than about programming, per se.

Answer (score 1):

Following Flimzy's comment to my question I figured it out. As he stated you can't run stuff that relies on X from systemd, so instead I run it automatically from my .i3/config file (I use I3 window manager). Thanks again to Flimzy for helping me with that.